# Workaround for specific generic type parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

The situation:

I have two protocols, one with a static method:

```
protocol DataSourceable {
    static func getMoreData<T: DataAccepting>(someObject: T)
}

protocol DataAccepting {
    func accept(data: [Any])
}
extension DataAccepting where Self: UIViewController { }
```

which compiles fine.

Once I define a class with a type parameter conforming to `DataSourceable`:

`class SampleViewController<T: DataSourceable>: UIViewController {...}`

I get a `Segmentation Fault: 11` and the compiler crashes.

```
    0  swift                    0x0000000112445b6d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
    1  swift                    0x00000001124455b6 SignalHandler(int) + 470
    2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffa4bd9bba _sigtramp + 26
    3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000002 _sigtramp + 1531077730
    4  swift                    0x000000010f8bd5bd swift::irgen::emitCategoryData(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::ExtensionDecl*) + 2285
    5  swift                    0x000000010f8c2425 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitGlobalDecl(swift::Decl*) + 1189
    6  swift                    0x000000010f8c1e85 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile&, unsigned int) + 133
    7  swift                    0x000000010f98dfe2 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1282
    8  swift                    0x000000010f85c1c7 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 23687
    9  swift                    0x000000010f854265 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17029
    10 swift                    0x000000010f81182d main + 8685
    11 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffa49cd255 start + 1
    12 libdyld.dylib            0x00000000000000c6 start + 1533226610
    **More_Stuff**...
    While emitting IR for source file /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/SampleViewController.swift
```

The end goal is to be able to do this:

```
class SampleViewController<T: DataSourceable>: UIViewController, DataAccepting {
var intArray = [Int]()
    func setup() {
        T.getMoreData(dataAcceptor: self)
    }

    func accept(data: [Any]) {
        intArray = data
    }
}

struct SampleModel: DataSourceable {
    static func getMoreData<T: DataAccepting>(dataAcceptor: T) {
        var anIntArray = [Int]()
        someObject.accept(anIntArray)
    }
}
```

And then make a `SampleViewController<SampleModel>`.
This will allow me to let the SampleModel deal with sourcing data for the controller. The SampleModel decides how to get the data, then using the accept() function on the controller it can give the data to the SampleController.

Comment: Well, shit. =/ Always sucks to see valid Swift causing compiler errors.

Comment: Though if you're going to be passing self as a parameter, why make it a static method in the first place? You can just make it an instance method with one parameter, and call `self.someProtocolMethod(num: 0)`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Hmm, I'm not sure that would accomplish the same behavior. Basically each type that conforms to `ProcotolA` needs a function that can accept an `Int` and an object of generic type `T`. Let me edit my question to make it a little more complicated ;). The type `T` in `someProtocolMethod()` also has a constraint.

Comment: The example is a bit too abstract for me to pick up what you're trying to do. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov just added some more descriptive names and details, does that make more sense?

Comment: still not sure why that can't be achieved with instance methods

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov so doing `self.getMoreData()` would mean the implementation of `getMoreData()` would have to be in `SampleController`, not in `SampleModel`. The only reason I'd like to try out this pattern is so I could later reuse the `getMoreData()` method from `SampleModel`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126944/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-marshall-white).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a compiler bug. However, you should avoid this design in general, as we discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126944/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-marshall-white).